# Unable to load image in notification in background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

i am using Firebase Push Notifications in my android app. App is showing image notification, but the problem is, when my app goes in background, it is not showing image.
(I used background service to show notification.)

Comment: Please what do you refer to as "showing image notification" Are you talking about the app icon that shows up on the notification?

Comment: @SundayGAkinsete no no... I am talking about image notification.